# Excel Macro to change entire column to uppercase

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to update a workbook I have to change all the emails from lowercase to uppercase.
I'm not that savvy with macros yet, but I came up with this one, but it takes forever to run. (only about ~1k rows).

```
Sub Uppercase()
   ' Loop to cycle through each cell in the specified range.
   For Each x In Range("B:B")
      ' Change the text in the column to uppercase letters.
      x.Value = UCase(x.Value)
   Next
End Sub
```

Is there something better I should be using?

tl;dr I need to change entire columns case, to uppercase.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't need a loop at all, this should take care of it basically instantly:

```
Sub tgr()

    With Range("B1", Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
        .Value = Evaluate("INDEX(UPPER(" & .Address(External:=True) & "),)")
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, that did take care of it instantly.

Comment: It gives `#VALUE!` when only B1 has value in B column

Answer (score 3):

Do the whole range at once:

```
Range("B:B") = [index(Upper(B:B),)]
```

Comment: It looks like everyone agrees with you. But to be honest... I have no idea where that goes. Do you mind putting context behind it? Or posting the finished code? I'm like elementary level coding of macros here... But I'm trying to learn.

Comment: Well, it would go inside your Sub.

Comment: Alternatively if it is a one off just plop it into the debug window (CTRL-G inside the VB Editor in Excel) and press enter

Comment: Oh, that's literally the whole code. ha. ok. that's what i misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead. You loop through every cell in column B, which is why it is slow.

```
Sub Uppercase()
   ' Loop to cycle through each cell in the specified range.
   For Each x In Range("B1:B" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row))
      ' Change the text in the column to uppercase letters.
      x.Value = UCase(x.Value)
   Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This range loop will still be slow if the range is long, the single short approaches above are better.

Answer (score 0):

Good, but using such a feature on a Selection is much more user friendly.

```vb
Sub ToUpper()
    For Each cell In Selection
        If Not cell.HasFormula Then
            cell.Value = UCase(cell.Value)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```